# Como anadir animate.css

Tags: html, css, animación, animate.css

Necesito usar [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) pero no se como incluirlo en mi html.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https:/raw.github.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css ">
<button class="animate flash"> myAnimatedButton </button>
```

Basicamente quiero que el boton cargue esos estilos. Como puedo usar desde aqui animate.css?

Comment: quieres que el botón se vea como en la pagina de la librería? o deseas añadir la librería de animación, ya que son dos cosas diferentes.

Comment: lo que quiero es la animacion. Anadir la libreria y que al darle ejecutar desde stackoverflow me cargue el boton con la animacion.

Comment: La dirección exacta del archivo animate.css es https://raw.github.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en que no dejas cargar primero la librería puedes hacer lo siguiente cuando este cargado el dom hacer un cambio de clases para ejecutar la animación

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').addClass('animated rotateInDownLeft');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<button> myAnimatedButton </button>
```

---

## Actualización

sin jQuery puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
//obteniendo el elemento que deseas animar
var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
//agregando el atributo class y sus valores
elemento[0].setAttribute("class","animated rotateInDownLeft")
```

```js
//obteniendo el elemento que deseas animar
var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
//agregando el atributo class y sus valores
elemento[0].setAttribute("class","animated rotateInDownLeft")
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<button> myAnimatedButton </button>
```

Comment: Funciona, pero usando jQuery. Un ejemplo de como hacerlo bien sin jQuery?

Comment: @Theia he modificado la respuesta usando javascript

Comment: Entonces el codigo javascript se ejecuta luego de que carga el dom?

Comment: así es, si requieres algunas veces se puede poner `document.readyState` y conocer en que estado se encuentra, mas informacion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState